# How to restrict which files are selectable from WKWebView UI delegate in runOpenPanelWith?

Tags: wkwebview

In a webpage I host in a WKWebView I want to allow selecting certain file types to open. For that I wrote a TS function to select files:

```js
/**
 * Allows the user to select a local file.
 *
 * @param contentType Restricts the file selection to specific file types.
 * @param multiple If true, allows to select more than a single file.
 *
 * @returns A promise that resolves to a single file or a list of files.
 */
export const selectFile = (contentType: string, multiple: boolean): Promise<File | File[] | null> =>
    new Promise((resolve): void => {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "file";
        input.multiple = multiple;
        input.accept = contentType;
        document.body.appendChild(input);

        input.onchange = (): void => {
            const files = input.files ? Array.from(input.files) : null;
            if (multiple) {
                resolve(files);
            } else {
                resolve(files ? files[0] : null);
            }
        };

        input.click();

        document.body.removeChild(input);
    });
```

As you can see there's a content type that can be specfied. In my WKWebView UI delegate I open a file selection panel:

```swift
  /**
   * Called when the web app requests a local file name.
   */
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
               runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters,
               initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
               completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
    let panel: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel.init();
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = parameters.allowsMultipleSelection;
    panel.canChooseDirectories = parameters.allowsDirectories;
    panel.canChooseFiles = true;
    panel.resolvesAliases = true;

    panel.begin { (result) in
      if result == .OK {
        completionHandler(panel.urls)
      } else {
        completionHandler(nil)
      }
    }
  }
```

However I cannot restrict the selectable files (according to the specified content type, e.g. `application/json`). The given parameters do not contain any value that would help here. So, how can I pass on the content type to the UI delegate function or otherwise make it aware of the possible file types?

Comment: you should try this contentType for validate it : application/JSON